# Providing React Context to an imported node module

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-redux

Is it possible to ES6 import a React component from node_modules that depends on a Context Provider (like react-redux 6.0) without the Provider Context being exported by that module?

For example, the implementation of the import would wrap the imported component with its own Provider.

```
import App from 'app-package'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('example'),
);
```

this works in react-redux 5.1.1 but not in 6.0.0, I assume because 6.0.0 is now using the React Context API.  The problem may also be webpack related.

Answer (score 2):

Found this https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13336.

It seems that `<App/>` must have its own Provider Context since it is outside of the imperative boundary.

To share store with `<App/>`, one can use [ReactReduxContext.Consumer](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/accessing-store) and pass store as a prop to it (via a component wrapper)